# show text value of selected option in multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a subscription form with a category dropdown select field. The text value of the selected option has to display 4 times in the form. It's 1 form.

```
<select name="catid" onchange="copy()" id="catid" class="inputbox required">
  <option value="" >Selecteer Categorie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="62" >Huurwoning</option>
  <option value="58" >Kamerhuur</option>
  <option text="kamerhuur" value="59" >Parkeren</option>
  <option value="60" >Vakantiewoning</option>
  <option value="61" >Bedrijfsruimte</option>
</select>
```

Do you have suggestions?

Comment: `$('#catid').on('change', function() { $('#elem1, #elem2 ....').text(this.value);  });`

Comment: And how can i show them on the page itself? as for: You are posting in category: 'value of the option'

Comment: @adeneo—`this.value` will return the **value** of the selected option (if it has one), not its text (which it seems the OP is after).

Answer (score 1):

This will get text of selected option when changed

```
 $('#catid').on('change', function() {
   /* get text of selected option*/
   var txt=$(this).find('option:selected').text();
   /*  change text of elements*/
   $('#elem1, #elem2 ....').text(txt); 
});
```

Without any html samples is hard to know what you need for text insertion

Comment: You could use `var txt = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;` which would be a lot more efficient.